# Is it allowed to include the battery state (0x2A1A) in the battery service?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

The specification for the BLE GATT battery service only lists the battery level characteristic although the descriptive text mentions "battery level *and state*".  I would like to indicate the battery charging/discharging state, however the characteristic that allows that (2A1A) is not included in any defined service.  It seems this is an oversight by Bluetooth SIG.

Will including an additional characteristic in the battery service for battery state be flagged as non-compliant with the specification?

Will the addition of the battery state characteristic cause any issue with iOS or android centrals?  For example will ios core bluetooth allow accessing a characteristic that is not list in the battery service specification?

I tried asking Bluetooth SIG directly about this and got back a non-answer indicating I should post my question here.