# What does Battery level state (0x2A1B) Bluetooth specification mean?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, bluetooth-gatt

**Battery Level State (0x2A1B)** is not listed under [Battery Service](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.service.battery_service.xml) specification in Bluetooth docs, only the **Battery Level (0x2A19)** is. However, when reading the characteristic **Battery Level State (0x2A1B)** under Battery Service, the 0x2A1B characteristic is found and `false` is returned, instead of an error or `null`.

Found this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539535/how-to-get-the-battery-level-after-connect-to-the-ble-device), where `true` is returned when reading the **Battery Level (0x2A19**, org.bluetooth.characteristic.battery_level), which is listed as one of the value fields in the description of **Battery Level State (0x2A1B)**.

Battery Level State "includes" Battery Level, as per the [specs](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.battery_level_state.xml):

[image: Battery Level State Description]

EDIT: When reading the **Battery Level State (0x2A1B)** using the Nordic Connect Android app, this is the Value: `Invalid data syntax: (0x) 64, "d"`.

**Questions:**

1. What Bluetooth Service does **Battery Level State (0x2A1B)** falls under? Is it the **Battery Service**, as `false` is successfully returned? Other [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45946565/is-it-allowed-to-include-the-battery-state-0x2a1a-in-the-battery-service) asks this of **Battery Power State (0x2A1A)**, which is also listed under **Battery Level State**. How does this work?
2. What does the `false` and `true` indicate as returned from reading the characteristics?

-

**Background:**
I am trying to read battery level via an Android app from an nRF51822 module (based on [Adafruit Bluefruit 32u4 LE](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-32u4-bluefruit-le/overview)).

Among discovered services and characteristics are **Battery Service (0x180F)** and **Battery level state characteristic (0x2A1B)**. Also tried adding custom characteristic to read battery level, as per [Adafruit tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/introducing-adafruit-ble-bluetooth-low-energy-friend/ble-gatt) but the newly added characteristic is not found by the Android app. However, reading the characteristic using AT commands works - the module returns an `int`.

I am reading the **0x2A1B** characteristic within `onServicesDiscovered`. Other characteristics I can read successfully. Here is the code within the Android app, based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539535/how-to-get-the-battery-level-after-connect-to-the-ble-device):

```
static String BATTERY_SERVICE_UUID = "0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
static String BATTERY_LEVEL_UUID = "00002a1b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";

@Override
public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
    if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
        //Read the battery level
        getbattery(gatt);
    } 
}

void getbattery(BluetoothGatt mGatt) {
    BluetoothGattService batteryService = mGatt.getService(BATTERY_SERVICE_UUID);
    if(batteryService == null) {
        Log.i("BATTERYX", "Battery service not found!");
        return;
    }
    Log.i("BATTERYX", "Battery service found!");

    BluetoothGattCharacteristic batteryLevel = batteryService.getCharacteristic(BATTERY_LEVEL_UUID);
    if(batteryLevel == null) {
        Log.i("BATTERY", "Battery characteristic not found!");
        return;
    } Log.i("BATTERYX", "Battery characteristic found!");
    Log.i("BATTERYX", String.valueOf(mGatt.readCharacteristic(batteryLevel)));
}
```

Here is the full list of discovered services and characteristics.

```
## SERVICES
[{UUID=00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, NAME=Service Unknown}, 
{UUID=00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, NAME=Service Unknown}, 
{UUID=00001530-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123, NAME=Service Unknown}, 
{UUID=0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, NAME=Service Unknown}, 
{UUID=6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e, NAME=SERIAL_TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID}, 
{UUID=0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, NAME=BATTERY_SERVICE_UUID}]


## CHARACTERISTICS
[[{UUID=00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, NAME=Characteristic Unknown}, //Device
{UUID=00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, NAME=Characteristic Unknown},   //Appearance
{UUID=00002a04-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, NAME=Characteristic Unknown}],  //Peripheral Preferred Connection Parameters
[{UUID=00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, NAME=Characteristic Unknown}], //Service Changed

[{UUID=00001532-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123, NAME=Characteristic Unknown}, 
{UUID=00001531-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123, NAME=Characteristic Unknown}, 
{UUID=00001534-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123, NAME=Characteristic Unknown}],

[{UUID=00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, NAME=Characteristic Unknown}, //Manufacturer Name String
{UUID=00002a24-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, NAME=Characteristic Unknown},  //Model Number String
{UUID=00002a28-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, NAME=Characteristic Unknown},  //Software Revision String
{UUID=00002a26-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, NAME=Characteristic Unknown},  //Firmware Revision String
{UUID=00002a27-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, NAME=Characteristic Unknown}], //Hardware Revision String

[{UUID=6e400003-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e, NAME=SERIAL_TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC}, 
{UUID=6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e, NAME=Characteristic Unknown}],

[{UUID=00002a1b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, NAME=Characteristic Unknown}]] //Battery level state
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Battery Level State should gives you battery level form 0 to 64 (100) percents